# AWS EC2 instance running out of memory running NodeJs application, cannot identify root cause because of log suppression

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, oom, outofmemoryerror

As stated in the title we have a NodeJS application running on an EC2 instance on AWS which sporadically runs out of memory and kills the process.

Business wise it is not really a hindrance since redundant systems make sure another instance spins up and is made available through the load balancer. But we would still like to find out what it is that cause the instance to run out of memory so that we may prevent it entirely.

We have looked though the logs surrounding the killing of the process to try and find out what is happening, but due to no memory being available it appears that the OS is unable to write any logs during that time. After it kills the process it logs that it has suppressed a number of logs and then it continues like normal. We therefor assume that the log suppression is preventing us from getting more information on the actual cause of the problem.

We have already attempted to turn off log suppression, but it still doesn't log anything during the time the process is unresponsive except now it doesn't report the number of logs that it suppressed.

Any idea how we might find out what it causing the process to run out of memory?

Answer (score 0):

> and kills the process.

The **first** thing you need to do is stop running out of memory. Reduce the overcommit on the host.

Add a new file in /etc/sysctl.d containing (initially):

```
vm.overcommit_memory = 2
vm.overcommit_ratio = 15
```

Then run `sudo sysctl -p`
(you may wish to adjust the ratio later).

Then you can start looking for whatever is consuming lots of memory.